# How to combine input with output tensors to create a recurrent layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, tensor

I'm trying to change a layer that calculates an output with ny outputs to a layer that calculates a recurrent output so the output has the same shape as the input. For example, consider the following

```
nt = 1000
nx_in = 8
ny = 2

x_train = np.array(shape=(nt, nx_in))
input = keras.Input(shape=(1, None, x_train.shape[1]), name='x_input')
output_ny = layers.Dense(ny)(x_input)
```

The above generates the expected results.  Now I would like to create a recurrent layer by generating a new output tensor that has the same shape as the input tensor and is created by taking one value from tensor output_ny, and (nx_in/ny-1), or 3, values from tensor input

```
print('x_input.shape: ', x_input.shape)
print('ny_output.shape:', ny_output.shape)
print('max_lag: ', max_lag)

output_list = list()
ky_start = 0
max_lag = 5
stored_lags = max_lag - 1
for iy in range(ny):
    ky_end = ky_start + stored_lags - 1
    print('append output, {}:{}'.format(iy, iy+1))
    output_list.append(ny_output[:, :, :, iy:(iy+1)]) 
    print('append input, {}:{}'.format(ky_start, ky_end))
    output_list.append(x_input[:, :, :, ky_start:ky_end])
    ky_start = ky_end + 1 

outputs = tf.unstack(output_list, axis=3)
```

The printed output is

```
x_input.shape:  (?, 1, ?, 8)
ny_output.shape: (?, 1, ?, 2)
max_lag:  5
append output, 0:1
append input, 0:3
append output, 1:2
append input, 4:7
```

This generates the following error message

```
ValueError: Dimension 3 in both shapes must be equal, but are 1 and 3. Shapes are [?,1,?,1] and [?,1,?,3].
    From merging shape 2 with other shapes. for 'packed' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [?,1,?,1], [?,1,?,3], [?,1,?,1], [?,1,?,3].
```

How to generate a new output tensor that has the same shape as the input tensor, and is built by appending one element from tensor output_ny, and 3 elements from tensor input, for each ny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate your layers, you can use keras.layers.Concatenate:

`outputs = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=3)(output_list)`

Thus, if you print outputs shape, it gives the expected result:

```
> print(outputs.shape)
(?, 1, ?, 8)
```

Comment: There appear to be two answers, one is to use Concatenate, and the other is to use matrix multiplication to place the output in the proper position, and also to shift the inputs correctly.  Then add those two terms.  Using either method, the next error is AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes' which I believe stems from not using a layer component.

Answer (score 0):

The Tensorflow "graph" is a Directed Acyclic Graph of computations. The backpropagation algorithm walks this graph backwards, and prediction walks it forwards.

My understanding is that you are trying to introduce a cycle into the graph. This will not work.

If you start from a basic implementation of neural networks, you can add your own recurrent cell.

Comment: I didn't do a good job at the description.  The model predicts the values at the next time step, in this case x_train[i+1, [0, 4]) = output_ny, is calculated corrected.  But, I would like feed into another step to calculate x_train[i+2].  So, the input for the next step can be written as [ny[i, 0], x_train[i][0:3], ny[i, 1], x_train[i][5:7]].  That's what I'm trying to create.  Anyway, it's still a sequential neural network, with two constant multiplications of the  input and output, and sum of those two terms.